# laravel and xampp cache

Tags: laravel, xampp, laravel-blade

My problem is that I am using laravel.blade.php and everytime I make a change to it and refresh browser, code does not update therefore not showing changes I have made, cache is disabled in apache and I have deleted laravel cache files however changes are still not being made on the browser.

Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Try to run command - `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: That kind of solved the issue as I also have seperate html files to be injected into a page, these seem to have updated, but not my blade.php

Comment: See my posted answer below for detailed info!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of cache problem in laravel, you can use these commands to solve the cache issue:

```
composer dump-autoload <----- this will reload all the autoloaded files again
php artisan config:clear <----- this will clear the config cache
php artisan config:cache <----- this will first clear the cache, and cache it again
```

> See more about [Config Caching in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration#configuration-caching)

Hope this helps!